# Font-size increases the top margin

Tags: html, css

Why is it that if I do font-size:70px or 120px, the distance between the top and the text increases?

**EDIT : Apparently, I fixed it by changing the line-height.
Is there a default line-height?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you haven't shown any code I will make the assumption that you're not using any styles beyond:

```
body
{
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

Every browser has a different default stylesheet, so the actual values may vary.

Typically the default `line-height` is `1em` or `100%` (same thing). On certain elements such as `p` and `h#`, there is a top and bottom margin by default. For `p` tags, the margin is `1em` and for `h#` it varies widely (`1.5em` for `h1`, `1.25em` for `h2` etc).

`em` and `%` values are based off of the font-size. If you have a paragraph element with a font-size of `30px`, by default it will have a `30px` top and bottom margin.

Comment: So how come i cannot change such margin when I apply the size of the font. ie. if i do margin:0 or margin-top:0, it will not put it into place

Comment: then maybe it *is* the line-height that is your issue. The size of the typeface does **not** mean that every letter in the text will fill the specified height. When you make the font-size very large, the spacing above and below the letters will become more pronounced. It is very difficult to debug your issues when you don't provide a comp or ***any*** code.

Comment: Please tell that: - **Why** the <p> Element's Top & Bottom margin is **Exactly Equal** to its Font Size??.

Comment: the unit `em` is based off of the current `font-size` of the element, `1em` means `100% current font-size value`.

Comment: So if you have an h1 with a font size of 3em, how would you add 30px of bottom margin so that the h1 responds correctly to my bottom margin

Comment: @andystructible, what's the base font-size that 3em is based off of? it'd be `(30 / <base-font-size>)em`

Answer (score 1):

html elements like p tag and h tags are having the default margin so i recommend always start writing any css with below code in your css file.

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

In above css line '*' defines all the elements in a page, so we are making all the elements default margin and padding to 0 and with this we don't need to give margin and padding to 0 each and everytime for p and h tags.

Answer (score 0):

Headings have margin and padding in it as default. So, if the margin and padding is '0', then you won't be getting any space above or below the heading text.

```
h1 { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

But you can always change the amount of margin and padding in the heading.
I hope this was helpful.